# "Unable to send mail" error message when changing user password in Magento Admin (v 2.2.1)

Tags: magento-2.1, zend-framework, smtp

I have a Magento 2.2.1 Running on a Amazon Lightsail VPS (the Bitnami Magento stack).

It has been working just fine, an previously I would get a "Password reset information" e-mail from the system whenever I tried to change the password of a user.

Now, however, if I try to set a new password, the page just reloads with an "Unable to send mail" error message being displayed at the top.

[image]

I'm using the [SMTP App for Magento 2](https://github.com/magepal/magento2-gmailsmtpapp) plugin to handle mail, and when I go to Stores > Configuration > Advanced > System and test the mail set-up I successfully receive an e-mail from the system.

I have also verified that the e-mail addresses of the user accounts I am trying to reset the password for are valid.

UPDATE, I'm pasting the code from my _sendMail() function below.

```
    public function _sendMail()
{
    set_error_handler(array($this, '_handleMailErrors'));
    $result = mail(
        $this->recipients,
        $this->_mail->getSubject(),
        $this->body,
        $this->header);
    restore_error_handler();

    if ($this->_errstr !== null || !$result) {
        /**
         * @see Zend_Mail_Transport_Exception
         */
        #require_once 'Zend/Mail/Transport/Exception.php';
        throw new Zend_Mail_Transport_Exception('Unable to send mail. ' . $this->_errstr);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the code, the error is thrown in `\Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail`, in the `_sendMail()` method, apparently it is still trying to send through the PHP `mail()` functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, but where exactly do I find that piece of code? I have been looking for it in the app/code/ folder under htdocs but I have not been able to locate it.

Comment: True, it's in `/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Mail/Transport/Sendmail.php`

Comment: Excellent, I found the piece of code, and I pasted the _sendMail() method in the original post. Do you see any obvious errors there?